# How to get fee of voice call using twilio api

Tags: twilio, phone-call, price

I have just developed a project with a voice call function using Twilio API.
It does work well but I need to know how much it payed for each call.
For example let assume voice call from "+1 USNumber" to "+44 EngNumber" for 5 mins.

**So How to calculate the fee?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [price of a call is available in the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) after the call is complete. It is available on a [call resource as the `Price` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties). The only thing is it is not necessarily available immediately. You might want to create a batch job once a day that runs through your calls for the day and harvests the costs of each call.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have just one more question. I want to know fee for per minuntes.
And how to get it?

Comment: You can find the pricing on twilio.com or you can use the [pricing API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/pricing).

Comment: Hello Philnash, Would you please do me a favor?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664471/how-to-set-budget-maximum-call-price-in-twilio-account
I have same question as this but I can't find answer and I want to know why this question is closed.

Comment: The question is closed because the Stack Overflow community expects the person asking to have tried something first and then ask why then attempt didn't work. The questioner was just asking how to do something. We don't have a way to set a maximum price on a call, so you're going to need to time your call from your server and [hang up the call using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) when it runs out of time.